# Para que serve o sinal de cifrão antes de uma variável?

Tags: shell-script

Gostaria de saber a função do cifrão, e também se é necessário que a variável esteja grudada ( sem nenhum espaço ) no sinal de igual ( = ) e no valor da variável ( GABRIEL ) e por que?

exemplo:

```
NOME="GABRIEL"
echo $NOME
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Serve para acessar valores armazenados dentro das variáveis. Quando usar o prefixo `$` você estará querendo acessar esse valor. Veja um exemplo bem simples.

```
#!/bin/sh

NAME="Zara Ali"
echo $NAME
```

Declarei uma variavel NAME e armazenei o valor "Zara Ali". Para **ACESSAR** esse valor "Zara Ali", eu preciso do prefixo `$`

Comment: @JJoao Onde? No meu código não tem. Você pode editar o código do usuário que fez a pergunta.

Comment: @JJoao agora entendi, eu editei o código. Muito obrigado por avisar.

Answer (score 3):

Em Unix em geral há possibilidade de escolher a "shell" que se pretende usar.
Exemplo: bash dash zsh sh ksh csh ... Cada uma tem a sua definição sintática e semântica.

Em várias distribuições de Linux e Mac, a shell por omissão é a bash: vamos partir do princípio que estamos a falar **Bash**. Segue-se algumas convenções:

**Identificadores**

- Por omissão os identificadores são comandos, ficheiros, pastas, argumentos : há necessidade de "marcar" as variáveis de algum modo.

**Definição de variáveis / atribuição**

- `id=exp`  atribuição de um valor a uma variável
- `id = exp` executa o comando "id" passando-lhe como argumentos "=" e "exp"
- `id= date` atribui o valor vazio a id e executa `date`

**Acerca do `$`** dependendo do contexto, pode significar muita coisa diferente:

- `$id` valor da variável id
- `echo "o meu username é $USER"` o valor da variável é expandido dentro de strings entre aspas (imprime "o meu username é jj")
- `$(comand)` dá como resultado a stdout do comando
- `$((3 + 4 + $a ))` dá como resultado o cálculo aritmético nele contido
- `a=(v0 v1 v2 v3 v4 v5) ; echo ${a[2]}` dá o segundo valor de um array (v2)

Um pequeno exemplo:

```
$ A=ano
$ echo "o $A passado foi $(( $(date +%Y) - 1))"
o ano passado foi 2016
```

Por fim, lembra-se que a bash tem:

- variáveis, arrays, dicionários
- estruturas de controlo (if, while, switch, for, ...)
- funções (incluindo recursivas)